# Mouse hover event not working

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

Working on a Bigcommerce site (stenciul theme) and trying to get a tooltip (color with PMS value) to show when a user hovers over a color swatch. However, can't get it to fire/work. Nothing happens on a mouseover.

Here is the section of code for the swatches. I added a class name of 'tooltip' to the span tag I want to grab the title from:

```css
    .tooltip {
     //display: inline;
     position: relative;
    }
  
    .tooltip:hover {
     background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
     border-radius: 5px;
     bottom: 10px;
     color: #fff;
     content: attr(title);
     left: 20%;
     padding: 5px 5px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
    <input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="attribute[12175]" value="1061" id="attribute_1061"  required>
        <label class="form-option form-option-swatch" for="attribute_1061" data-product-attribute-value="1061">
            <span class='form-option-variant form-option-variant--color tooltip' title="Graphite (PMS Black 7)" style="background-color: #4E4B49"></span>
        </label>
```

Any help is appreciated....

Comment: Where is the css for the swatch? You have a hex code for the color white; is the tooltip supposed to change to white when you hover, or the swatch?

Answer (score 1):

Your `:hover` in css in working fine, see below, you weren't able to get result as you were using the css on nothing. I just wrote random words inside span containing your `tooltip` class to check it and see its working fine.

```css
.tooltip {
      //display: inline;
      position: relative;
    }
  
    .tooltip:hover {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
      border-radius: 5px;
      bottom: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      content: attr(title);
      left: 20%;
      padding: 5px 5px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
<input class="form-radio" type="radio" name="attribute[12175]" value="1061" id="attribute_1061"  required>
        <label class="form-option form-option-swatch" for="attribute_1061" data-product-attribute-value="1061">
                        <span class='form-option-variant form-option-variant--color tooltip' title="Graphite (PMS Black 7)" style="background-color: #4E4B49">fdgergerg</span>
        </label>
```